# How to show a hidden P element with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

here's JS:

```
function mygtux(){
    var metai = prompt("Kiek tau metu? ");

    if (metai >= 20 && 39 >= metai) {
         $("p").show(200);
    } else {
         alert("nesaunuolis :D ")
    }
};
```

I have hidden p element with p hidden

so, what can I do? nothing really happens, it just stays hidden no matter what.

You can find more of this code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ckaxx6co/#

Comment: Any output in the console? Is jQuery (or any other framework) correctly included?

Comment: Put the rest of your code (html, css and javascript) related with this issue. In jsfiddle  will much better.

Comment: stackoverflow hides my Html, I'm not sure why. :D  Sort of new here, so I'm not sure yet what to do about it, but alright.

Comment: copy your html , select code and press ctrl + K.

Comment: I put this one in https://jsfiddle.net/ckaxx6co/# does it help? The idea is to press a button and get some questions. Answer them and accordingly show some p elements that are hidden. Right now all I get are questions, so this part works. I answer them and nothing happens, this   $("p").show(200); part doesn't work, or at least I don't put it correctly so it could work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding JQUERY resource properly then it should work, since it is one thing missing in your fiddle other than small formatting issue.

```css
.ddropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left:2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ddropbtn" onclick="mygtux()">Spausk cia ir suzinok savo! </button>

   <p hidden style="color:black"> some code later on </p>
   
   <script>
   function mygtux(){
        var metai = prompt("Kiek tau metu? ");
    
           
           if (metai >= 20 && 39 >= metai){
                  $("p").show(200);
           } else{
                alert("nesaunuolis :D ")
            }
       };
   </script>
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nx4wcdtt/

Comment: Hey, thanks man! I've been trying to solve this for hours,did this and that and it seems, that all I needed to do is to put a script for JQ, but I somehow totally forgot. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Acuriousguy Protip: learn how to use the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). One look at the error message would have saved you hours of work.

Comment: @Acuriousguy You are welcome. as JJJ told developer console is the THE way to look for such issues.